# jquery append seems to mess up my code

Tags: jquery

hi i'm trying to dynamically append some divs and then use jquery on them such as the click event, but it does not work, i have no idea why it's acting this way..

```
$("#addGenreFinal").click(function () {
     var genre = $('#newGenreTxt').val();
     $("#txtAddGenreContainer").slideUp();
     $('#otherFavContainer').append('<div class="songTilesGenreContainer"><div class="addSongsBtnContainer icons" ><img src="../../Content/images/add.png"             style="padding:10px;"/></div><div style="float:right;padding-right:26px;padding-    bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;color:#949494;font-size:20px;">' + genre + '</div></div>');
     $('#newGenreTxt').val('');
    });

    $(".songTilesGenreContainer").click(function () {
        alert('hello'); 
    });
```

why the alert box is not popping out, when i use other pre defined classes it works but it doesnt on dinamically appened elements hmm...

Comment: thanks all mind - blown :D just learned a new thing

Comment: It sounds like there was an answer you liked.  If this is the case, please accept the answer.  This will remove the question from the unanswered list, and encourage continued help in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind the event using live as the element is added later to the document

```
$(".songTilesGenreContainer").live("click", function () {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".songTilesGenreContainer").click(function () {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Should change to:

```
$(".songTilesGenreContainer").live('click', function () {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Because the element you were trying to bind to did not exist when the code above ran. `.live()` is for just this purpose:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future

Here is a link to jQuery documentation for `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/

`.delegate()` is a preferred method if you have a container element for the element you are binding to. Rather than bubble all the way up to the document object, `.delegate()` will bubble the event up to the selected root element. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

An example with `.delegate()`

```
$('#otherFavContainer').delegate(".songTilesGenreContainer", 'click', function () {
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".songTilesGenreContainer").live("click", function () {
        alert('hello'); 
    });
```

Try using live instead of .click. .click does a bind behind the scenes. Since .bind only binds on elements in that selector which exist on the DOM at the time of execution it will not find your dynamic content. .live will attach to elements added to the dom even AFTER the code has run.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the click handler to the genre container after the append; since you're adding it outside of the `#addGenreFinal` click handler it's not being added to anything.

You can also use the [`.live()` (docs)](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to add the handler to selectors that haven't been created yet.